# Jquery resize the form "formAddNewRow"

Tags: jquery-plugins

When I click on Add button , the formAddNewRow form opens , but I want to increase the widht of this form how do I achieve this ?

Here is what I tried

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

        var r;
        var oTable = $('#Lookup').dataTable({
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "aLengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, 100, -1], [10, 25, 50, 100, "All"]],
            "iDisplayLength": 25

        }
).makeEditable({
    oAddNewRowFormOptions: { title: 'Add user', width: 800 },
            "aoColumns": [
                          { 
                              cssclass: 'required'

                          },
                          { tooltip: 'Click to edit',
                              cssclass: 'required'

                          },
                          { tooltip: 'Click to edit',
                              cssclass: 'required'

                          }

                          ],

            fnShowError: function (message, action) {
                switch (action) {
                    case "update":
                        jAlert(message, "Update failed");
                        break;
                    case "add":
                        jAlert(message, "Update failed");
                        break;

                }
            }

        });

    });
```

But the Addnewform stays the same , the width of the form is not increased ? Any suggestions . can you please point me in the right direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also had the same problem, but after some searching I found the answer: place this in your document.ready function: (if you just want to change the width as the same of your content, just change it to auto)

```
$("#formAddNewRow").dialog({width:'650px'})
```